# How to send out an AJAX request to Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to send an AJAX request to my server to obtain a string and save it.

This is my relevant JS:

```
var token = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'payment_demo.py',
        success: function(data) {
            token = data;
        },
      });
```

This is my relevant Python (Flask):

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('official_checkout_page.html')

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def client_token():
    return gateway.client_token.generate()
```

The HTML and JS both are loaded, but I get a 404 not found on the ajax URL (payment_demo.py).
Right now the locations are /payment_demo.py, /static/official_checkout_page.js (the JS file), /templates/official_checkout_page.html (the HTML file, if necessary). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you look at the request in your network console, is it going to the url you expect it to be going to?

Comment: * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2018 18:39:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2018 18:39:58] "GET /static/official_checkout_page.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2018 18:39:58] "GET /payment_demo.py HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: So yes... I think so but it doesn't find it

Comment: Click the request and look at the actual url that it shows in the right hand side that pops up.

Comment: How does one click on the request

Comment: You only have routes for `/`, not `payment_demo.py`... AJAX doesn't need to know  your filenames

Comment: Ok, I replaced the url with '/' and it worked. But when I console.log(token), it's giving me the full HTML page (official_checkout_page.html). I've confirmed that gateway.client_token.generate() will generate an alpha-numeric string. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ajax request just get data from the spesifik url from server/api resource, please try this code

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/token',
        success: function(data) {
            token = data;
        },
      });
```

**the example Flask code from backend server**

```
 from flask import jsonify, render_template
 @app.route('/')
 def home():
   return render_template('official_checkout_page.html')

 @app.route("/api/token", methods=["GET"])
 def client_token():
   return jsonify({"data":gateway.client_token.generate()})
```